# When and why would I need a jboss-deployment-structure.xml for a Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, web-deployment, jboss-eap-6

I am trying to understand how to use JBoss EAP6 with Spring applications. I have a sample OpenShift application and it contains a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file.

I found some [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/Add_an_Explicit_Module_Dependency_to_a_Deployment1.html) about this file, but I am not clear why and when one should use those files with Spring applications. The content is the following:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
   <deployment>
       <dependencies>
            <module name="com.h2database.h2"/>
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl"/>
            <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl"/>
            <module name="org.slf4j"/>
       </dependencies>
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Why does one need to declare dependencies to modules? And what are modules in the JBoss paradigm? Is it possible to live without this xml file?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As long as you don't have any classloading problems with your application you don't need the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file. But once you have trouble of such kind the dependency management in jboss-deployment-structure.xml would be your friend.

The article [Modularized Java with JBoss Modules](https://web.archive.org/web/20190517214713/http://planet.jboss.org/post/modularized_java_with_jboss_modules) explains what modules are very well.

I think in short you can say that everything that is deployed as WAR, JAR or EAR is a module. These modules are referred to as *dynamic modules*. Beside them there are *static modules* in $JBOSS_HOME/modules. The only difference is how they are packaged.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I found on the internet:

*"In order to avoid using JBoss provided logging APIs, we need to place the following kind of “jboss-deployment-structure.xml” file inside “/home/userone/ApplicationLevelLog4jDemo/src” so that we can exclude the jboss logging APIs for our application and our application can use it’s own version of logging APIs."*

Source: [http://middlewaremagic.com/](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=1458)