# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream in uploading file with SpringMVC/Wildfly/CentOS

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload, wildfly

While I successfully upload files to my web application in SpringMVC/Widlfly/Ubuntu stack, I encounter NoClassDefFoundError exception in SpringMVC/Widlfly/CentOs.
Both stack has same Wildfly, same JDK, and same configurations.

Environment:

- SpringMVC
- Wildfly 8.1 / Wildfly 8.2
- JDK 1.7.0_51-b13
- JAR files:

  - my-ear.ear/my-web.war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar
  - my-ear.ear/my-web.war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
  - wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/commons/io/main/commons-io-2.4.jar

I know that this exception is due to conflicting in class-loader.

Comment: Make sure this class exist in jar file `org/apache/commons/io/output/DeferredFileOutputStream` and let us know.

Comment: have you checked you jboss deployment structure references the correct dependency

Comment: @MiyaG Yes, that class exists.

Comment: @KennethClark How can I check that?

Comment: The 'jboss-deployment-structure.xml' will be in the war if it is produced take a look at the following article **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581980/when-and-why-would-i-need-a-jboss-deployment-structure-xml-for-a-spring-applicat**

Comment: @KennethClark Yes. I removed 'commons-io-2.4.jar' from my WEB-INF/lib and added <module name="org.apache.commons.io"/> dependency in 'jboss-deployment-structure.xml' file, but exception occurred again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem. 
I moved '*commons-io-2.4.jar*' and '*commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar*' files from '**my-ear.ear/my-web.war/WEB-INF/lib/**' to '**my-ear.ear/lib**'.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I was declaring the dependencies into `a war maven project`, so maven was copying the `jar libs` into `WEBINF/lib`.

I solved this issue by putting the dependencies declaration on another war dependent jar project pom, instead war project as i was doing:

**myapp-project-web-api/:** <- (war maven project)

```
pom.xml:

...
    <dependencies>

      <!-- File upload -->
        <!-- deleted commons-fileupload dependency>

        <!-- deleted commons-io dependency -->
...
```

**myapp-project-web-api-components/:**

```
pom.xml:

...
    <dependencies>

    <!-- File upload -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      </dependency>
...
```